# Cocoapods project fails to build on an Apple Silicon / M1 Mac

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods, apple-silicon

**Before you think that this is a duplicate:**

There are several posts on this failing, but most of them are old posts not related to M1 Macs and some have contradictory solutions. This post is only for M1 Macs using Cocoapods with the following setup:

**The setup**

- Cocoapods 1.10.1
- Cocoapods configuration has `generate_multiple_pod_projects` and `incremental_installation` enabled
- Terminal is set up to use Rosetta 2 to solve issues with Cocoapods
- Several libraries used, such as Firebase, RxSwift etc and NearbyMessages

**The problem**

Compiling the project (that works on an intel computer) yields the following error for the NearbyMessages library from Google:

`In /Users/user/Pods/NearbyMessages/Libraries/libGNSMessages.a(GNSAudioModem.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/user/Pods/NearbyMessages/Libraries/libGNSMessages.a' for architecture arm64`

The most common suggestions are to add arm64 to "Excluded Architectures" and to set "Build Active Architectures Only" to YES (which is default). [Other posts](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657913) say that the latter should be NO. Setting this to No will instead give me the error `No such module 'RxSwift'`.

Adding arm64 to "Excluded Architectures" would also mean that I would need the following post install to all generated projects (since I am using `generate_multiple_pod_projects`) in the Pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to understand is if this is the correct approach. Not just try different settings and hope for the best, but to understand why this would help. Why would I exclude arm64 when the M1 chip is arm64? Have I been using the wrong solutions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question solved my problem lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NearbyMessages binary pod distribution has not been updated with a slice to support the M1 Mac. Therefore it is not possible to link it into an app and build it for the simulator.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if Google is planning to update the library?

Comment: Best to follow up on the NearbyMessages support channels.

Comment: What support channel would that be? I sent feedback several times via the "send feedback"-button on the project's webpage. Is there any other way to get in touch with them?

Comment: If I'm the owner of such a pod, what info can I look up or what changes should I make to make the pod compile on Apple silicon?

Comment: The pod should package an `xcframework` instead of a `framework` and the `.xcframework` should include an `arm64` slice for the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

> config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] =
> "arm64e"

Initially with **e** in the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).